# regex parser and custom escape chacter

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string that I'd like to pick out sub-strings from that start and end with a plus sign.

example:

```
text +name+ filler with /+ sign +b+ bold text +/b+
```

I'd like to pick out the `+name+` `+b+`and the`+/b+`, but my current regex would treat `+ sign +` as a possible value"

this is the regex I am using `\+[\-@\w\s\d\/\!]*\+`

I've tried adding a `[^/]` in front, but that adds whatever character there was before the `+` and cannot deal with `+n++b+`

I'm trying to figure out the lookaround and lookbehind, just not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negative lookbehind looks like this `(?<!/)`. This only matches if the previous character is not a `/`.

Example:

```
(?<!/)\+[^+]*\+
```

Note:

- You may have to escape the `/` if you are using that character as the delimiter for your regular expression.
- Not all regular expression engines suport lookbehinds.

Comment: that's what it was (wrong engine)...  thanks, and thanks for optimizing the `[^+]`